# Imported incorrect time zone in data extension with sync REST API

Tags: rest-api, dataextensions

If I send a data with time zone via sync API (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/postDataExtensionRowsetByKey.htm), e.g. `2018-03-12T09:39:45.815+01:00`. In the SFMC DE there is `3/12/2018 2:39:45 AM`. That means -7h. Why?

Comment: It is because Salesforce expects the data to be in UTC timezone.  Were you able to find a fix for this?